# htaccess rewrite rule doesn't work with dashes?

Tags: url-rewriting

my htaccess rule isn't working with rewrite with dashes in:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ index.php?do=$1 [QSA]
```

so, www.domain.com/rules works, however, www.domain.com/about-us doesn't

I've verified that www.domain.com/index.php?do=about-us works so it's definately a rewrite issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regular expression doesn't include a check for dashes - try:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z\-]+)$ index.php?do=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 5):

Your regex only takes a-z and A-Z, change it to [A-Za-z\-] so it will include the **-** character